# Can gcal automate highlighting days on|off for this "shift work" roster?

Tags: shell-script, command-line, calendar

I've been reading the man page for gcal, and I'm unsure if I can do the following:

Description: I would like to print a roster with the output like cal -y but highlight all days a person is rostered on.

The Roster is a repeatable pattern of:
4 days on, 3 days off, then 5 days on, 4 days off.
(This pattern repeats over the whole year)

```
    start from date: [year,month,day]
    for the whole year:
    { 
     highlight 4 days // Working
     skip 3 days      // Days off
     highlight 5 days // Working
     skip 4 days      // Days off
   }
    print output to screen as year calendar
```

thanks for your time.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What is the end goal? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Description: I would like to print a roster with the output like cal -y but highlight all days a person is rostered on.

The Roster is a repeatable pattern of: 4 days on, 3 days off, then 5 days on, 4 days off. (This pattern repeats over the whole year). Thanks for prompting me to write  the question better.